# SwiftUI TabView gives an error message during add/delete the element of CoreData

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, swiftui, swiftui-tabview

I am currently trying to use TabView for carousel view(PageTabViewStyle) with CoreData.

The error doesn't occur, when I add a new page in order like this age.name: 3, page.name: 4, page.name: 5

But the error occurs, if I put a number in the first/middle order like page.name: 2

If I put page.name: 6, then no error and it's also same with Alphabet.
b c d e -> put "f", no problem, but put "a" error.

After turn off the app and open the app, then I see the updated(Page added/Page deleted) ContentView anyway.

I guess, TabView has a sorting problem, so I tried to sort the list of CoreData, change LifeCycle to SwiftUI, but the error occurs again and again.
I've also tried with Firebase, but the same problem.

**Error Message:**

```
"libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete item 1 from section 0 which only contains 1 items before the update'
    terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"
```

**ContentVIew**

```
TabView() {
    ForEach(pages, id: \.self) { page in
        SubPage(whichPage: page)
    }
}
.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
.indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
```

**AddPage**

```
let page = Page(context: self.moc)
        page.name = pageName

        do {
            print("page.name: \(page.name ?? "Unknown")")
            try self.moc.save()
            
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
```

**SubPage**

```
@FetchRequest(entity: Page.entity(),
              sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Page.name, ascending: true)]
) var pages: FetchedResults<Page>

var whichPage: FetchedResults<Page>.Element
```

Using VStack or HStack or List instead of TabView works fine without any problem.

Comment: `TabView` is not really flexible you would have to create your own `View` to mimic it.

Comment: I've run into the same problem. Hoping someone here can offer a solution that allows us to continue to use TabView.

Comment: @tkhelm I've checked just now that this problem is solved in Xcode 13 Beta & iOS15!

Comment: I'd like to point our this questions and accepted answer for a very simple iOS 14 workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68423533/12764795

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, this problem is solved in Xcode 13 & iOS 15 based!

**Full Code**

```
TabView {
    ForEach(pages) { page in
        SubPage(whichPage: page)
    }
}
.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
```

or

```
TabView {
    ForEach(pages) { page in
        SubPage(whichPage: page)
    }
}
.tabViewStyle(.page)
```